# Fiction and non-fiction references together

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the best way to mix fictional and non-fictional references in a text eg;

Billy and Mike are fictional and wrote a song (fictionally) that is sung by a singer played by an actress whose name is Dawn Waters.

Can I say that *Dawn sang the song that Billy and Mike wrote*. I know I could say this in certain informal situations but what would be more correct for a more formal situation without getting totally technical.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably Writing Advice (and therefore off-topic).

However you could use something like one of the following

> - Dawn sang the song written by the characters Billy and Mike.
> - Dawn sang the song "Billy" and "Mike" wrote.

It's clear that Billy and Mike are not real, and (by implication) that Dawn is.

Comment: I think I've read novels with the usual disclaimer ('All characters appearing in this work are fictitious. Any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.') which then go on to mention famous historical persons. Confusing.